# Filling TableView in Xcode with Swift

Tags: swift, tableview

I have one ViewController in Xcode, in which I added two Buttons, one view **and one TableView** (not a table view controller).

I want to have vier rows in the table in which I can add some date, which are changing sometimes.

Now I have one problem:
I have a class in which I will control that stuff:

```
import UIKit

class DeviceTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 4
    }

    /*
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Now I want to connect that with the view. Thats why I want to change the class of the tableView in the attributes inspector to DeviceTableViewController (name of my class). But Xcode will not do this.

How could I change that?

Comment: You have mentioned in your question as **, one view and one TableView (not a table view controller).** but the class is of `UITableViewController `

Comment: It's a viewcontroller, in which I have added one view and one TableView. in Xcode, tableview isn't the same as a tableviewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UITableViewController` is only able to handle the standard table controller provided by Apple. In order to create a controller with mixed views like you want, then you will need to subclass the standard `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`(which you currently have done).

I've tried to recreate a similar scenario like yours: A controller that has a `UIView`, two `UIButtons` and a `UITableView`. Notice that the `datasource` and `delegate` of the table view have been set in the storyboard, but you can do the same in code instead.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TableWithStuff
//
//  Created by Stefan Veis Pennerup on 18/05/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Kumuluzz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // MARK: - Models

    let model = ["Coffee", "With", "Milk", "Please"]

    // MARK: - Storyboard outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: - Storyboard actions

    @IBAction func firstButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    @IBAction func secondButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myAwesomeCell")!
        cell.textLabel!.text = model[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

[image: Storyboard of the controller]

[image: Datasource and delegate set in the storyboard]

[image: The final result]